# Change xib width in interface builder

Tags: interface-builder, size, dimensions

I try to change the dimensions of the view in interface builder from the size tab of the property inspector, however it is grayed out and doesn't let me.

Does anyone know how I can edit the dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well usually you cannot change dimensions of views when the status bar is set to 'grey'. Set status bar to 'none' and then try it out.

If that's not the case then I'm not sure at the moment. I usually do everything programmatically instead of use the IB, I hate working with .xibs

Comment: i would change the dimensions programmatically but that's not possible.  There is no function or attribute to change a views width.

Comment: Do you need to use the interface builder? If not, comment out the initwithnib method, and implement loadView, and in loadView you can access 'self.view.bounds.size.width' and set it as you wish.